# iOS: NSFetchResultsController sort on transient property (Swift)

Tags: ios, sorting, core-data, swift, transient

Say for example I have an `Entity` called **Tasks** with an `Attribute` called **date** and a `UITableView` populating this **Tasks** `Entity`.

This is what I currently see:

```
7-Dec-14 09:30
7-Dec-14 11:00
7-Dec-14 13:30
7-Dec-14 16:00
```

Now lets pretend the current time is actually 7-Dec-14 12:00 so the first 2 rows have passed but the second 2 rows are in the future. I want to split these into Groups within the `UITableView`.

I've found I can create a Transient Property on the Entity as follows:

```
var dateGroup: NSNumber {
    get {
        if date.compare(NSDate()) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending {
            return 0
        } else {
            return 1
        }
    }
}
```

This works and now shows the `UITableView` as follows, when I set sectionNameKeyPath: "dateGroup":

```
Group 0
7-Dec-14 09:30
7-Dec-14 11:00
Group 1
7-Dec-14 13:30
7-Dec-14 16:00
```

My trouble is how can I get the `UITableView` to actually display the results like this (so future tasks above the expired tasks):

```
Group 1
7-Dec-14 13:30
7-Dec-14 16:00
Group 0
7-Dec-14 09:30
7-Dec-14 11:00
```

I've tried creating a `NSSortDescriptor` on the transient property (dateGroup) but this doesn't work.

I realise this is happening because my `NSSortDescriptor` on the "date" attribute. But I don't know how to search for rows where date > currentDate, followed by date < currentDate.

I think basically what I want to do is swap the sections around IF there is more than 1.

Hope this makes sense. How would you tackle this sorting issue?

## Update

OK, I've completely rewritten it to use 2 x `FetchRequestControllers` self.upcomingFRC (section 0) and self.elapsedFRC (section 1) and the following is now working without any errors or nils.

All Inserts, Updates, Moves & Deletes are smooth and animated between both `FetchResultsControllers`.

Thank you very much pbasdf.

```
func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
    switch type {
        case .Insert:
            println("insert")
            if var indexPathNew = newIndexPath {
                if controller == self.elapsedFRC {  indexPathNew = NSIndexPath(forRow: newIndexPath!.row, inSection: 1)  }
                println("N indexPath : \(indexPathNew)")
                self.tableViewEvent.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathNew], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        case .Delete:
            println("delete")
            if var indexPathOld = indexPath {
                if controller == self.elapsedFRC {  indexPathOld = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath!.row, inSection: 1)  }
                println("O indexPath : \(indexPathOld)")
                self.tableViewEvent.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathOld], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        case .Update:
            println("update")
            if self.showLarge {
                if var indexPathOld = indexPath {
                    if controller == self.elapsedFRC {  indexPathOld = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath!.row, inSection: 1)  }
                    println("O indexPath : \(indexPathOld)")
                    if let largeCell = self.tableViewEvent.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathOld) as? LargeTableViewCell {
                        if      indexPathOld.section == 0 {  self.configureLargeCell(largeCell, frc:self.upcomingFRC, row:indexPathOld.row)  }
                        else if indexPathOld.section == 1 {  self.configureLargeCell(largeCell, frc:self.elapsedFRC, row:indexPathOld.row)  }
                    } else {
                        println("******************************************")
                        println("found nil largeCell - configure Large Cell")
                        println("******************************************")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("******************************************")
                    println("found nil indexPath - configure Large Cell")
                    println("******************************************")
                }
            } else {
                if let indexPathOld = indexPath {
                    if let smallCell = self.tableViewEvent.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPathOld) as? SmallTableViewCell {
                        if      indexPathOld.section == 0 {  self.configureSmallCell(smallCell, frc:self.upcomingFRC, row:indexPathOld.row)  }
                        else if indexPathOld.section == 1 {  self.configureSmallCell(smallCell, frc:self.elapsedFRC, row:indexPathOld.row)  }
                    } else {
                        println("******************************************")
                        println("found nil smallCell - configure Small Cell")
                        println("******************************************")
                    }
                } else {
                    println("******************************************")
                    println("found nil indexPath - configure Small Cell")
                    println("******************************************")
                }
            }
        case .Move:
            println("move")
            if var indexPathOld = indexPath {
                if controller == self.elapsedFRC {  indexPathOld = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath!.row, inSection: 1)  }
                println("O indexPath : \(indexPathOld)")
                self.tableViewEvent.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathOld], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
            if var indexPathNew = newIndexPath {
                if controller == self.elapsedFRC {  indexPathNew = NSIndexPath(forRow: newIndexPath!.row, inSection: 1)  }
                println("N indexPath : \(indexPathNew)")
                self.tableViewEvent.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPathNew], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            }
        default:
            return
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake - you should use indexPath not newIndexPath to dequeue the cells (I will amend my answer).  Using the alternative dequeue (without specifying indexPath) should work OK, but you need to double check that you don't get a nil cell (whereas `dequeue... forIndexPath:` will throw an exception if it cannot find a prototype cell or registered class/nib).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would amend your tableView delegate and datasource functions, so that they "swap" the sections over.  For example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count = 2 {
        section = 1 - section
    }
    let sectionInfo = self.fetchedResultsController.sections![section] as NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo
    return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
}
```

and

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var newIndexPath : NSIndexPath
    if self.fetchedResultsController.sections!.count = 2 {
        newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row, inSection: (1 - indexPath.section))
    } else {
        newIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    self.configureCell(cell, atIndexPath: newIndexPath)
    return cell
}
```

Sadly you will have to do this for each of the functions.  Also beware if you use the fetched results controller to implement inserts/deletes etc, because you will have to make the same adjustment there.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for taking the time. I'm not near my computer to try this now but it does make sense and I'm sure it will work (note your comment on all the other areas to change too). My only other idea was to create 2 x `NSFetchedResultsController` one for Expired and one for Upcoming. Would this be a bad idea?

Comment: Having two FRCs is certainly do-able.  I have this working for two separate entities displayed in one tableView, whereas you would presumably just have mutually exclusive predicates (which would avoid the need for the transient property).  You would just need to watch out for the FRC delegate methods firing at the same time (or interleaved).

Comment: Thanks. So are you saying that because I am querying the same Entity it would be simpler (or even more stable) to use a Transient Property (like in my first post) and then just switch the Sections over? Finally, am I right in thinking that by only adding a Transient Property I do not need to migrate my Core Data to a new database on next upgrade?

Comment: I'm not sure which is the simpler (I'm afraid I don't know whether adding a transient property will require a migration).  I like the 2 FRC approach; my only hesitation is how the FRC delegate functions would handle an edit to a Task which effectively moved it from Expired to Upcoming or vice versa - both FRCs would fire the delegate functions more or less simultaneously.  It might all work like a dream!

Comment: Thanks for your help. Will try both situations in a few hours and let you know how I get on. Cheers

Comment: Updated original question with current issue.

Comment: Getting closer. Updated original again.

Comment: Is that row on screen at the time?  The cell can validly be nil if that row has scrolled off screen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66414/discussion-between-richard-and-pbasdf).

Comment: Sorry - now available in chat.