# TableView section update depend on CoreData transient property change

Tags: ios, uitableview, sorting, core-data, transient

I'm trying to develop a timetable app.

I have TableViewController which shows the classes on current day. In viewDidLoad( ) I fetch the classes with NSFetchedResultsController:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lessons")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "startsday = '\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))'", NSDate())
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
let sortDescriptorStarts = NSSortDescriptor(key: "starts", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptorTitle = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptorStarts, sortDescriptorTitle]
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: nil)
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
fetchedResultsController.performFetch(nil)
```

And when I set sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier"(which is a transient property) they are sorted into three groups "Past", "Now", "Next" depend on current time. It is working. I have a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqLwt.png) here.

My problem is: **As time goes by the sections aren't updated**
*The rows should move out and move in other sections and eventually they should all go into the "Past" section, and the "Now", "Next" sections should be deleted.*

I can update the sectionIdentifier transient property, but my fetchedResultController doesn't want to notice the changes...

I don't want to use tableView.reloadData( ) because i want animations.

(There is a [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347181/ios-nsfetchresultscontroller-sort-on-transient-property-swift) question, but the end of it is different. I can't get my answer.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem. It is definitely not the best but it's working nicely. (Swift 2.3)

First, I have a transient property called "sectionIdentifier".This could be "NOW", "NEXT" and "PAST" depend on the current time.I added a new persistent property next to this transient called "sectionID". This property's purpose is to tell if the lesson status (NOW, NEXT, PAST) changed. I changed my original fetch to this:

```
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Lessons")
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "startsday = '\(dateFormatter.stringFromDate(NSDate()))'", NSDate())
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
let sortDescriptorStarts = NSSortDescriptor(key: "starts", ascending: true)
let sortDescriptorTitle = NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)
fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptorStarts, sortDescriptorTitle]
fetchRequest.fetchBatchSize = 30
fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "sectionIdentifier", cacheName: nil)
fetchedResultsController.delegate = self
do {
    try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
} catch _ {
   //Handle error
}
if let lessons = fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as? [Lessons] {
    for lesson in lessons {
        if lesson.sectionID != lesson.sectionIdentifier! {
            lesson.setValue(lesson.sectionIdentifier!, forKey: "sectionID")
            moc.refreshObject(lesson, mergeChanges: true)
        }
    }
}
```

After the fetch I set this persistent property to the transient's value. (last 8 line above)

In viewDidLoad() I added this line.

```
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(TodayViewController.update), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I update my transient property every second.
My update method looks like this:

```
func update() {
    for lesson in fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects as! [Lessons] {
        if lesson.sectionID != lesson.sectionIdentifier! {
            lesson.setValue(lesson.sectionIdentifier!, forKey: "sectionID")
            moc.refreshObject(lesson, mergeChanges: true)
            do {
                try moc.save()
            }
            catch _ {
                //Handle error
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my transient property will always give the lessons current status and the persistent one will alway give the tableviewcell's status. If there is difference I put my transient value into the persistent property and with moc.refreshobject() i will get a the proper FetchedResultControllerDelegate method and i can handle the tableview changes there.